# Is there a way to get the font on my phone onto my tablet?

Tags: fonts

I have a Galaxy S5, and it has a built in font called "UDRGothic". I think it's near perfect for mobile use, and so I want to also have it on my Galaxy Tab A 10.1 tablet.

It doesn't seem to be available by default on my tablet, so of course, [I Googled](https://www.google.co.jp/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=UDRGothic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=WJBAWf3GNsOD4gLli5rACg) it, but all that came up with was a link to [some page that describes an associated APK file](https://census.tsyrklevich.net/file_permissions//system/app/UDRGothic), but doesn't seem to have a download option. If I try [a more nuanced Google search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=UDRGothic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=WJBAWf3GNsOD4gLli5rACg#channel=fs&q=UDR%20Gothic%20font%20download), I get tons of options for various Gothic fonts, but none are the font I'm looking for.

Is this font only for use with my phone, or can I maybe copy it from my phone to my tablet, or get it some other way?

Comment: Could we get a picture of the font, some example? And in fonts menu could you make a screenshot of the font where you select it, is there any other who you can select?

Answer (score 1):

A pre-answer note, I'm typing in the mobile Stack Exchange app, so please excuse any spelling errors.

Yes, there is a way, but it requires your tablet to be rooted.

As with most things, go ahead and take a backup of both devices, you never know what could go wrong.

OK, lets begin!
In a file manager of your choice, head into `/system/fonts`, on the device that has the font you like. This does not require root, because your are only reading from that file, not writing.

Find out a way to copy the font file to your tablet. I would recommend just emailing the font file to yourself, and downloading it from the email onto the tablet.

Now on the tablet, rename that font file to something memorable, like `goodfont.ttf`. You are going to have to sacrifice the current font, or you can take a backup of the default font file. (If I'm correct I believe it's `Roboto-Regular.ttf`, but it might be different on yours.)

Now copy `goodfont.ttf` into `/system/fonts` (remember, this is on the tablet), and rename it `goodfont.ttf` to `[default font name here].ttf`.

Hope I was helpful!

Comment: Thank you for responding! Unfortunately, neither device is rooted, so I'm not sure if this solution can be applied.

Comment: @Questioner Im guessing rooting isnt an option either?

Comment: No, unfortunately it isn't. I have tried rooting before, but, long story short, there were problems, and I had to return to stock.

Comment: @Questioner I might be able to help you get it rooted. I would need to know the story, but I think it's possible. If you still want to root it of course.

Comment: I appreciate the offer! Unfortunately, I think rooting is not an option for me because when I tried that before, it invalidated certain digital wallet applications I use with Felica.

Comment: Ah. I understand